# Applying a Window function to calculate differences in pySpark

Tags: pyspark, window-functions, apache-spark-sql

I am using `pySpark`, and have set up my dataframe with two columns representing a daily asset price as follows:

```python
ind = sc.parallelize(range(1,5))
prices = sc.parallelize([33.3,31.1,51.2,21.3])
data = ind.zip(prices)
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data,["day","price"])
```

I get upon applying `df.show()`:

```python
+---+-----+
|day|price|
+---+-----+
|  1| 33.3|
|  2| 31.1|
|  3| 51.2|
|  4| 21.3|
+---+-----+
```

Which is fine and all. I would like to have another column that contains the day-to-day returns of the price column, i.e., something like

`(price(day2)-price(day1))/(price(day1))`

After much research, I am told that this is most efficiently accomplished through applying the `pyspark.sql.window` functions, but I am unable to see how.

Comment: I assume sqlCtx is the equivalent to 'spark' object which is obtained using sc = SparkContext('local')
spark = SparkSession(sc)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can bring the previous day column by using [lag](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lag.html) function, and add additional column that does actual day-to-day return from the two columns, but you may have to tell spark how to partition your data and/or order it to do lag, something like this:

```python
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

dfu = df.withColumn('user', lit('tmoore'))

df_lag = dfu.withColumn('prev_day_price',
                        func.lag(dfu['price'])
                                 .over(Window.partitionBy("user")))

result = df_lag.withColumn('daily_return', 
          (df_lag['price'] - df_lag['prev_day_price']) / df_lag['price'] )

>>> result.show()
+---+-----+-------+--------------+--------------------+
|day|price|   user|prev_day_price|        daily_return|
+---+-----+-------+--------------+--------------------+
|  1| 33.3| tmoore|          null|                null|
|  2| 31.1| tmoore|          33.3|-0.07073954983922816|
|  3| 51.2| tmoore|          31.1|         0.392578125|
|  4| 21.3| tmoore|          51.2|  -1.403755868544601|
+---+-----+-------+--------------+--------------------+
```

Here is longer introduction into [Window functions in Spark](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html).

Comment: Hi. Thanks! That is very useful. By the way, what does the "lit" function do?

Comment: `lit` - Creates a Column of literal value - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lit

Comment: minor note. it's also good practice to sort the column that lag applies to, e.g. Window.partitionBy("user").orderBy("day", ascending=True)

Comment: Evaluating df_lag, I get an error: Window function lag(price#66, 1, null) requires window to be ordered, dfu.withColumn('prev_day_price',func.lag(dfu['price']).over(Window.orderBy("user"))) solves this

Comment: How this can be achieved using spark structured streaming?

Comment: Can any one suggest how this can be implemented using Spark Streaming?

Answer (score 7):

**Lag** function can help you resolve your use case.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

### Defining the window 
Windowspec=Window.orderBy("day")

### Calculating lag of price at each day level
prev_day_price= df.withColumn('prev_day_price',
                        func.lag(dfu['price'])
                                .over(Windowspec))

### Calculating the average                                  
result = prev_day_price.withColumn('daily_return', 
          (prev_day_price['price'] - prev_day_price['prev_day_price']) / 
prev_day_price['price'] )
```