# Calculate difference between value in current row and value in first row per group - pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this DataFrame:

```python
DataFrame[date: string, t: string, week: string, a: bigint, b: bigint]
```

With the following data:

```python
+---------+--+--------+---+---+
|date     |t |week    |a  |b  |
+---------+--+--------+---+---+
|20180328 |1 |2018-W10|31 |35 |
|20180328 |1 |2018-W11|18 |37 |
|20180328 |1 |2018-W12|19 |37 |
|20180328 |1 |2018-W13|19 |38 |
|20180328 |1 |2018-W14|20 |38 |
|20180328 |1 |2018-W15|22 |39 |
|20180328 |1 |2018-W16|23 |39 |
|20180328 |1 |2018-W17|24 |40 |
|20180328 |1 |2018-W18|25 |40 |
|20180328 |1 |2018-W19|25 |41 |
|20180328 |1 |2018-W20|26 |41 |
|20180328 |1 |2018-W21|26 |41 |
|20180328 |1 |2018-W22|26 |41 |
|20180328 |2 |2018-W10|14 |26 |
|20180328 |2 |2018-W11|82 |33 |
|20180328 |2 |2018-W12|87 |36 |
|20180328 |2 |2018-W13|89 |39 |
|20180328 |2 |2018-W14|10 |45 |
|20180328 |2 |2018-W15|10 |45 |
|20180328 |2 |2018-W16|11 |48 |
|20180328 |2 |2018-W17|11 |55 |
|20180328 |2 |2018-W18|11 |60 |
|20180328 |2 |2018-W19|11 |70 |
|20180328 |2 |2018-W20|11 |79 |
|20180328 |2 |2018-W21|11 |86 |
|20180328 |2 |2018-W22|12 |93 |
+---------+--+--------+---+---+
```

And I want to add a new column that has, for each date and type (column `t`), the difference between that row and the first week for that date for column `b`.

Something like this:

```python
+---------+--+--------+---+---+---+
|date     |t |week    |a  |b  |h  |
+---------+--+--------+---+---+---+
|20180328 |1 |2018-W10|31 |35 |0  | 
|20180328 |1 |2018-W11|18 |37 |2  |
|20180328 |1 |2018-W12|19 |37 |2  |
|20180328 |1 |2018-W13|19 |38 |3  |
|20180328 |1 |2018-W14|20 |38 |3  |
|20180328 |1 |2018-W15|22 |39 |4  |
|20180328 |1 |2018-W16|23 |39 |4  |
|20180328 |1 |2018-W17|24 |40 |5  |
|20180328 |1 |2018-W18|25 |40 |5  |
|20180328 |1 |2018-W19|25 |41 |6  |
|20180328 |1 |2018-W20|26 |41 |6  |
|20180328 |1 |2018-W21|26 |41 |6  | 
|20180328 |1 |2018-W22|26 |41 |6  | 
|20180328 |2 |2018-W10|14 |26 |0  | 
|20180328 |2 |2018-W11|82 |33 |7  | 
|20180328 |2 |2018-W12|87 |36 |10 | 
|20180328 |2 |2018-W13|89 |39 |13 | 
|20180328 |2 |2018-W14|10 |45 |19 | 
|20180328 |2 |2018-W15|10 |45 |19 | 
|20180328 |2 |2018-W16|11 |48 |22 | 
|20180328 |2 |2018-W17|11 |55 |29 | 
|20180328 |2 |2018-W18|11 |60 |34 | 
|20180328 |2 |2018-W19|11 |70 |44 | 
|20180328 |2 |2018-W20|11 |79 |53 | 
|20180328 |2 |2018-W21|11 |86 |60 | 
|20180328 |2 |2018-W22|12 |93 |67 | 
+---------+--+--------+---+---+---+
```

Each number in column h is the value in col('b') - value in col('b') at W10 for that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a [`pyspark.sql.Window`.](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window)

Partition by the column `'t'` and order by the column `'week'`. This works because sorting your week column will do a lexicographical sort, and `'W10'` will be the first value for your group. If this were not the case, you would need to find another way to sort the column so that the order is what you want.

Here is a trimmed down example.

```python
data = [
    ('20180328',1,'2018-W10',31,35),
    ('20180328',1,'2018-W11',18,37),
    ('20180328',1,'2018-W12',19,37),
    ('20180328',1,'2018-W13',19,38),
    ('20180328',1,'2018-W14',20,38),
    ('20180328',2,'2018-W10',14,26),
    ('20180328',2,'2018-W11',82,33),
    ('20180328',2,'2018-W12',87,36),
    ('20180328',2,'2018-W13',89,39)
]

df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data, ['date', 't', 'week', 'a', 'b'])
df.show()
#+--------+---+--------+---+---+
#|    date|  t|    week|  a|  b|
#+--------+---+--------+---+---+
#|20180328|  1|2018-W10| 31| 35|
#|20180328|  1|2018-W11| 18| 37|
#|20180328|  1|2018-W12| 19| 37|
#|20180328|  1|2018-W13| 19| 38|
#|20180328|  1|2018-W14| 20| 38|
#|20180328|  2|2018-W10| 14| 26|
#|20180328|  2|2018-W11| 82| 33|
#|20180328|  2|2018-W12| 87| 36|
#|20180328|  2|2018-W13| 89| 39|
#+--------+---+--------+---+---+
```

**Using pyspark DataFrame functions**

Define the Window:

```python
from pyspark.sql import Window   
w = Window.partitionBy('t').orderBy('week')
```

Create the new column using the Window:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = df.select('*', (f.col('b') - f.first('b').over(w)).alias('h'))
df.show()
#+--------+---+--------+---+---+---+
#|    date|  t|    week|  a|  b|  h|
#+--------+---+--------+---+---+---+
#|20180328|  1|2018-W10| 31| 35|  0|
#|20180328|  1|2018-W11| 18| 37|  2|
#|20180328|  1|2018-W12| 19| 37|  2|
#|20180328|  1|2018-W13| 19| 38|  3|
#|20180328|  1|2018-W14| 20| 38|  3|
#|20180328|  2|2018-W10| 14| 26|  0|
#|20180328|  2|2018-W11| 82| 33|  7|
#|20180328|  2|2018-W12| 87| 36| 10|
#|20180328|  2|2018-W13| 89| 39| 13|
#+--------+---+--------+---+---+---+
```

**Using pyspark-sql**

Here is the equivalent operation using pyspark-sql:

```python
df.registerTempTable('myTable')
df = sqlCtx.sql(
    "SELECT *, (b - FIRST(b) OVER (PARTITION BY t ORDER BY week)) AS h FROM myTable"
)
df.show()
#+--------+---+--------+---+---+---+
#|    date|  t|    week|  a|  b|  h|
#+--------+---+--------+---+---+---+
#|20180328|  1|2018-W10| 31| 35|  0|
#|20180328|  1|2018-W11| 18| 37|  2|
#|20180328|  1|2018-W12| 19| 37|  2|
#|20180328|  1|2018-W13| 19| 38|  3|
#|20180328|  1|2018-W14| 20| 38|  3|
#|20180328|  2|2018-W10| 14| 26|  0|
#|20180328|  2|2018-W11| 82| 33|  7|
#|20180328|  2|2018-W12| 87| 36| 10|
#|20180328|  2|2018-W13| 89| 39| 13|
#+--------+---+--------+---+---+---+
```

**Related**

- [Applying a Window function to calculate differences in pySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725353/applying-a-window-function-to-calculate-differences-in-pyspark/)
- [Find maximum row per group in Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218882/find-maximum-row-per-group-in-spark-dataframe)
- [How to select the first row of each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878370/how-to-select-the-first-row-of-each-group)