# Pyspark - Not sure how to assign the sum of following X rows to the existing row value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The best way to explain is this by example. In this case we'll take the next two rows:

Original:

```
ID  val
1   2
1   3    
1   1
1   9
2   1 
2   6
2   8
2   1
```

Updated Version:

```
ID  sum_val
1   4
1   10    
1   9
1   0
2   14 
2   9
2   1
2   0
```

I'm working in PySpark since my dataset is quite large. I'm brand new to PySpark so I'm having trouble trying to make this work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725353/applying-a-window-function-to-calculate-differences-in-pyspark).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, sum, monotonically_increasing_id
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 1), (1, 9), (2, 1), (2, 6), (2, 8), (2, 1)],
    ("id", "val")
)
```

You'll need `Window` like this:

```
w = (Window.partitionBy("id")
           .orderBy("_id")
           .rowsBetween(1, 2))
```

add `_id`:

```
(df
   .withColumn("_id", monotonically_increasing_id())
   .withColumn("sum_val", sum("val").over(w))
   .na.fill(0)
   .show())

# +---+---+-----------+-------+          
# | id|val|        _id|sum_val|
# +---+---+-----------+-------+
# |  1|  2|          0|      4|
# |  1|  3|          1|     10|
# |  1|  1| 8589934592|      9|
# |  1|  9| 8589934593|      0|
# |  2|  1|17179869184|     14|
# |  2|  6|17179869185|      9|
# |  2|  8|25769803776|      1|
# |  2|  1|25769803777|      0|
# +---+---+-----------+-------+
```

Please beware that `monotonically_increasing_id` like this is not a good practice - in production you should always have ordering information embedded in the data itself, and never depend on the internal order of the `DataFrame`.