# How to implement a monthly lag when number of rows per month changes in PYSPARK?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a monthly lag in order to calculate monthly returns.

This is my dataframe:

| REG_DT_YYYYMM | TYPE_CD | production |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202005 | FC | 412316860416 |
| 202005 | LG | 420906795008 |
| 202005 | LK | 429496729600 |
| 202006 | FC | 438086664192 |
| 202006 | LG | 446676598784 |
| 202006 | LK | 455266533376 |
| 202007 | FC | 463856467968 |
| 202007 | LG | 472446402560 |
| 202007 | LK | 481036337152 |
| 202008 | FC | 489626271744 |
| 202008 | LG | 498216206336 |
| 202008 | LK | 506806140928 |
| 202009 | FC | 515396075520 |
| 202009 | LG | 523986010112 |
| 202009 | LK | 532575944704 |
| 202010 | FC | 541165879296 |
| 202010 | LG | 549755813888 |
| 202010 | LK | 558345748480 |
| 202010 | LT | 566935683072 |
| 202011 | FC | 575525617664 |
| 202011 | LG | 584115552256 |
| 202011 | LK | 592705486848 |
| 202011 | LT | 601295421440 |
| 202012 | FC | 609885356032 |
| 202012 | LG | 618475290624 |
| 202012 | LK | 627065225216 |
| 202012 | LT | 635655159808 |
| 202101 | FC | 644245094400 |
| 202101 | LG | 652835028992 |
| 202101 | LK | 661424963584 |
| 202101 | LT | 670014898176 |

I now want to create a lag so that I can compare monthly production values. My problem lies in the fact that we have an extra row LT from 202010 and later. Also, in the future there could be even more rows.

Comment: which values do you want to compare?

Comment: The production numbers, sorry for not specifying this.

Comment: for each type_cd?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Applying a Window function to calculate differences in pySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725353/applying-a-window-function-to-calculate-differences-in-pyspark)

Comment: I dont think so, as that examples works with a fixed lag. It only looks to the production column, while it also has to look to the 2 other columns.

Comment: How about `df.withColumn('lag_production', F.lag('production').over(Window.partitionBy('TYPE_CD').orderBy('REG_DT_YYYYMM')))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the previous row for each type by setting a partition in the lag window:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'lag_production', 
    F.lag('production').over(
        Window.partitionBy('TYPE_CD')
              .orderBy('REG_DT_YYYYMM')
    )
)
```