# Pyspark subtracting dataframe column from the next column and save the result to another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on a personal PySpark project for learning purposes and I have a peculiar problem.

I have a dataframe (df) with N columns, in which I want to subtract each column out of the next (e.g. `col1 - col2`, `col2 - col3`, ..., `col(N+1) - colN`) and save the resulting differences column in another dataframe.

I generate this df by parsing a JSON, saving to a pandas dataframe (schema: dates column, columns for each item) transposing the columns to rows (to have a single Items column and columns for each date) and then transforming it in a spark df. I do this because it seems that row by row operations in Spark are fairly difficult to implement.

I move the first column (the `Items` column) of the df to a new dataframe (ndf) so I am left with only the following schema (header is comprised of dates and the data is only integers):

| Date1 | Date2 | Date3 | ... | DateN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 104 | 98 | 98 | ... | 0 |
| 223 | 135 | 80 | ... | 0 |
| 143 | 122 | 114 | ... | 0 |
| 91 | 79 | 73 | ... | 0 |

I want to subtract the ints of column Date2 out of the ints from column Date1 (e.g. `df.Date1 - df.Date2`) and the resulting column of values (with the header of the larger column - `Date1`) to be saved/appended in the already existing ndf dataframe (the one in which I moved the column earlier). Then move on to subtract column Date2 and column Date3 (`df.Date2 - df.Date3`), and so on until column `Date(N+1) - DateN`, then stop.

The new Dataframe (ndf), created earlier from the Items column, would look like this:

| Items | Date1 | Date2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | 6 | 0 | ... |
| Item2 | 88 | 55 | ... |
| Item3 | 21 | 8 | ... |
| item4 | 12 | 6 | ... |

Practically, I want to see the number with which each item has increased from one date to the next.

I was thinking that doing it in a for loop. Something like:

```
# get list of column headers
dates = df.columns
# for index and header in list
for idx, date in enumerate(dates):
    if idx < len(dates)-1:
        # calculate df columns subtraction and add differences column to ndf
        df = df.withColumn(f'diff-{date}', F.when((df[date] - df[dates[idx+1]]) < 0, 0)
                        .otherwise(df[date] - df[dates[idx+1]]))
        ndf = ndf.join(df.select(f'diff-{date}'), how='full')
```

But this is very slow and I have a feeling that a for loop does not really take into account Spark's advantages and it might be way slower than using map/lambda.

Comment: This looks like an unnecessarily verbose approach. You can just use the dataframe without any transpose, and use window functions to get the difference from the previous row. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725353/applying-a-window-function-to-calculate-differences-in-pyspark/) for an example.

Comment: Thank you @mck . Your answer pointed me in a good direction and it helped me to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 solutions:

1. For the transposed dataframe, as I had it in my question above, a user on reddit r/dataengineering helped me with the solution:

   ```
   # list to save column subtractions
   col_defs = []
   # grab the date columns
   date_cols = df.columns[1:]
   # for index and column
   for i, date in enumerate(date_cols):
       if i > 0:
           # save the difference between each 2 columns to the list
           col_defs.append((df[date_cols[i - 1]] - df[date]).alias(date))
   # result df containing only the items column and the differences for each date
   result = df.select('county', *col_defs)
   ```
2. If I do not transpose the dataframe I can apply Window functions, as recommended by @mck in a comment to the question. I prefer this way as I avoid transposing, also the columns number will remain constant. This [resource on PySpark Window Functions](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-window-functions/) was very helpful for me to understand the way they function:

| Dates | Item1 | Item2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Date1 | 104 | 223 | ... |
| Date2 | 98 | 135 | ... |
| Date3 | 98 | 80 | ... |

```
# list to save column subtractions
colDiffs= []
# get only the item columns
itemCols = df.columns[1:]
# Window function spec to partition the entire df and sort it by Dates descending as there are no dates that show multiple times.
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy().orderBy(F.col('Dates').desc())
# for each item column
for item in itemCols:
    # add a new column, itemdiff, to the df containing the same numbers but shifted up by one 
    # e.g. if a column X contains the numbers [1, 2, 3], applying the lead window function with 1 as argument, will shift everything up by 1 and the new Xdiff column will contain [2, 3, none]
    df = df.withColumn(f'{item}diff', lead(item, 1).over(windowSpec))
    # append the difference between the current and the lead colum to the list
    colDiffs.append((df[item] - df[f'{item}diff']).alias(item))
# get the final df containing the subtraction results
result = df.select('Dates', *colDiffs)
```

Comment: How does it work for subtracting two [string columns within a single dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69540138/10452700) in PySpark?